# Override a function defined in wp-includes/comment-template.php

Tags: php, functions, filters, actions, pluggable

I need to override the function `get_cancel_comment_reply_link` or `cancel_comment_reply_link` that are defined in

```
wp-includes/comment-template.php
```

These functions are not listed in `pluggable.php`.

**How can I override them from my theme's `functions.php`?**

I tried

```
remove_filter('get_cancel_comment_reply_link', 'cancel_comment_reply_link');
add_filter('get_cancel_comment_reply_link', function($text='') { return ''; }, 1, 1);
```

without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the end of the function `get_cancel_comment_reply_link( $text = '' )` in the file `wp-includes/comment-template.php`, you see the filter `cancel_comment_reply_link`.

```
return apply_filters( 'cancel_comment_reply_link', $formatted_link, $link, $text );
```

It may work.

Comment: Thank you. How to disable this then, without modifying a file in wp-includes?

Comment: Try, in your `functions.php` for a  theme or a child theme, or in a plugin :

`add_filter(  'cancel_comment_reply_link', '__return_false' );`

Comment: I did `add_filter('cancel_comment_reply_link', function($link) { return ''; }, 10);` in the meantime and I confirm it works! Thanks! By the way, why does *adding* a filter work here? Does adding a filter override other functions? I thought that *adding* would execute *all* functions and not override the first one (defined in wp-includes). Do you have information about this?

Comment: Perhaps, it's the only time the filter is executed with the priority 10. You don't have to put here the priority, because 10 is the default. If the filter is used more than once, you may have to change the priority to be executed after. You need to define the same priority just to remove a filter with the function `remove_filter()`. But if the filter is defined inside a dynamic class, it's another more difficult story.